# Using Terms aggregation in Nest elasticsearch for a specific document

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, nest

I want to get popular terms in the content field of a specific document.
How can I do this?
So far, I have tried the code below but sounds like Filtering on a particular Document Id does not work.

```
 var result = client.Search<Document>(s => s.Index(defaultIndex).Filter(f => f.Term(t => t.Id, ID)).
     Aggregations(a => a.Terms("terms_agg",
     sa => sa.Field(p => p.File).Size(20))));
    var agg = result.Aggs.Terms("terms_agg");
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to get a list of popular terms in a specific content using Terms aggregation? Or if there is any other way in elasticsearch to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a filtered query for this.

```
var result = client.Search<Document>(s => s
    .Index(defaultIndex)
    .Query(q => q
        .Filtered(fq => fq
            .Filter(f => f
                .Term(t => t.Id, ID))))
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms(
            "terms_agg",
            sa => sa.Field(p => p.File)
    .Size(20))));
var agg = result.Aggs.Terms("terms_agg");
```

Reason for this is the scope of aggregation is the documents matched by the top level "query" section. The filter you are using is a post filter. Results of a post filter do not affect the scope of documents which get aggregated. In your request, the "query" section implicitly is a "match_all" query and hence you see multiple documents getting aggregated. By forcing the document filter inside the top level query section, you can limit the scope of aggregation.